# How to count specific words using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have simple mysql table:

```
id  server1   server2
1      Yes      Yes
2      Yes      No
3      No       No
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate how many "Yes" and "No" are in each column and then use that number in charts (like highcharts)

Comment: Please show us your attempts.

Comment: This seems to violate the [Zero, One or Infinite Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule). Columns like `server1` and `server2` are usually a sign the data is not properly [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calcualte number of word and output result in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599263/how-to-calcualte-number-of-word-and-output-result-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(server1 = 'Yes') as s1_yes,
       sum(server2 = 'Yes') as s2_yes,
       sum(server1 = 'No') as s1_no,
       sum(server2 = 'No') as s2_no
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use case statements like this

```
select server1,

sum(case when server1 = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as yes_count,
sum(case when server1 = 'no' then 1 else 0 end) as no_count

from yourtable
```